# MySQL execute statement that's in a comment

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

With MySQL (MySQL Workbench specifically), is there a way to execute a selected line of text that's in a comment?

A related question that would solve it also: is there a way to execute selected (highlighted) text, not the entire statement?

When doing ad-hoc queries and updates, I often surround risky sql with a comment, e.g.,

```
/*
INSERT INTO sometable
    ('one', 'two')
SELECT one, two
FROM anothertable
WHERE something = 42;
*/
```

or the -- comment style if it's a quick one

```
-- SELECT * FROM largetable
```

If I have several statements I'm working on, I don't want to accidently run the wrong one if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Ideally, I'd like to just position the cursor and execute the statement, even though it's a comment (that's odd, I know). Next best thing is to highlight the text to execute, and press something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easily possible:

[image]

If you have selected something it will be executed with the first menu entry, including commented text.

Comment: That's it! Thanks I missed that (and at first thought the blue line in your screenshot is what you meant). Execute selection, just like it says.